# What are the roots in this function.

Tags: matrix-calculus, calculus

I am trying to find roots for a particular function. It has reduced to the following expression.

$$
\frac{d f(\lambda)}{d \lambda}=8\lambda + 2\text{Trace}(Q\Sigma Q^\top)- \sum_i \frac{2 M_i}{1- 2\lambda M_i}
$$

$M$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $Q\Sigma Q^\top$. I refer $i$ as the diagonal values.

How to solve and find roots for $8\lambda + 2\text{Trace}(Q\Sigma Q^\top)- \sum_i \frac{2 M_i}{1- 2\lambda M_i} =0$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $tr(Q\Sigma Q^T)=\sum_im_i$ if I correctly understand the question.

Then the considered equation (I assume that the unknown is $\lambda$) is 
$8\lambda+\sum_i(2m_i-\dfrac{2m_i}{1-2\lambda m_i})=8\lambda-4\lambda \sum_i \dfrac{m_i^2}{1-2\lambda m_i}=0$ and $\lambda=0$ is a solution.

Otherwise $2=\sum_i  \dfrac{m_i^2}{1-2\lambda m_i}$ and you must find the real roots of a polynomial of degree $n$.